# Date and Time Delta between two Dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, array-difference

I have a table structure like below for completion of the task against name , I want to take difference between End_Time to Start_time for each name. Can anyone please suggest time how to do this with python code.

```
start_time  End_Time  Name
2018-08-05T00:15:00+05:30  2018-08-05T00:17:00+05:30  UM6217
2018-08-05T00:15:00+05:30  2018-08-05T00:19:00+05:30  UM28402
2018-08-05T00:15:00+05:30  2018-08-05T00:18:00+05:30  UM27746
2018-08-05T00:15:00+05:30  2018-08-05T00:16:00+05:30  UM34802
```

Time difference. I am using pandas dataframe to process this data

Comment: Python's datetime module has a timedelta function, plus tools for processing times stored as strings

Comment: DO you want difference in hours or days ?

Comment: @nosklo : the time format is different which available in this dataframe it's a timezone delta.

Comment: i want in Minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your time to `pandas.datetime` objects, and then simply subtract both.

```
df[['start_time', 'End_Time']] = df[['start_time', 'End_Time']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.str.split('+').str[0]))
df['diff'] = (df.End_Time - df.start_time).dt.total_seconds().div(60).astype(int) #minutes
```

Output:

```
           start_time            End_Time     Name  diff
0 2018-08-05 00:15:00 2018-08-05 00:17:00   UM6217     2
1 2018-08-05 00:15:00 2018-08-05 00:19:00  UM28402     4
2 2018-08-05 00:15:00 2018-08-05 00:18:00  UM27746     3
3 2018-08-05 00:15:00 2018-08-05 00:16:00  UM34802     1
```

Comment: After changes into pandas.datetime , the value of time has been changed form 00:15 hrs to 18:45 hrs. diff value is correct one but strt_time has not correct after conversion.

Comment: @DHANANJAYCHAUBEY, that is because it was taking `+5:30` (timezone) into consideration. Seems like you do not need it. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be this way too.

```
df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'])
df['End_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_time'])

df['DifferenceInMinutes'] = (df['End_time'].sub(df['start_time'], axis = 0)) / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')
```